# How can I make the size of a CSS grid grow to fit the background image?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm pretty new to CSS grids. I have been trying to make the CSS grid grow to fit the background image that I am trying to insert using CSS. What I have done works but I'm sure it's not the way to go about things.

```
.ads {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, auto);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(6, auto);
    .egg {
        height: 47vh;
        background-image: url("/images/mobile/image-transform.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

Comment: well `background-images` do not influence the size of an element. As the anme suggest they are just background. As such there is no way to set the element to fit a background-image then to hard code it.

Comment: So what I did setting a specific height is acceptable?

Comment: absolutely acceptable. Otherwise you need to inlcude the image as HTML with the `img`-tag. Highly depends on the sue case and what you itnend to do.